# My lang file loads twice when using angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

My `config.js` file looks like:

```
angular.module('mean').config(['$routeProvider', '$translateProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $translateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/items', {
      templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
      controller: 'ItemsController'
    }).
    when('/items/create', {
      templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
      controller: 'ItemsController'
    }).

    when('/articles/create', {
        templateUrl: 'views/articles/create.html'
    }).
    when('/articles/:articleId/edit', {
        templateUrl: 'views/articles/edit.html'
    }).
    when('/articles/:articleId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/articles/view.html'
    }).
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/index.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      prefix: '/lang/',
      suffix: '.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en-US');
    $translateProvider.useCookieStorage();
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');
  }
]);
```

I have an `en-US.json` file in the `lang` folder. But for some reason, this file loads twice as seen in the Firebug console:
[image]

Any thoughts as to why that might be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're setting the **fallbackLanguage** and **preferredLanguage** as the same one, so he needs to load "both". In this case preferredLanguage should be enough.